# TableLayoutPanel minimum row height or row padding

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have created a TableLayoutPanel with lots of rows and columns. Each cell has a label. Since a label can have multiple rows of text, and accordingly its height can vary, I want the table to grow and shrink accordingly, just as a typical HTML table would do. So, I set the row SizeType to AutoSize.

The problem is that the rows now tightly fit the labels, and look very crammed. I think I could solve this by setting a padding value to each label, but that does not look like a clean solution.

Is there any way to set a minimum row height when the SizeType is AutoSize, or set a row height padding?

Comment: If you have to use TableLayoutPanel then your solution seems to be the most accurate. Setting padding at each label will give you demanded look while TableLayoutPanel does not allow to set that property on "cell".